# Java - 2D arrays, checking for duplication

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates

The variable "num" is a 2D array. I'm trying to check in that array, if there are any duplicates. "num" is a user-input.

I have extensively looked through Java documentation and asked my lectures and I can't get a working answer. I understand the concept, what I'm meant to do, but just can't get the coding right.

Here is my code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ //3 rows with 5 numbers each
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            num[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter value for line: " + i + " and position: "+  j ));
            if((num[i][j] == num[i][0]) || (num[i][j] == num[i][1]) ||(num[i][j] == num[i][2]) || (num[i][j] == num[i][3]) || (num[i][j] == num[i][4])){
                if(num[i][j] != 0){
                    num[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "ERROR. Enter value for line: " + i + " and position: "+  j ));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have also tried using HashSet, but I think that only works with 1D arrays.

I would like to use something like this, as I feel this I understand the most:

```
    secret = new Random().ints(1, 40).distinct().limit(5).toArray();
```

But obviously not with Random.

I've tried this:

```
    Set<Integer> check = new HashSet<>();
    Random gen = new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ // 3 rows, 5 numbers
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            num[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter value for row " + i + " and position " + j));
            check.add(gen.nextInt(num[i][j]));
        }
    }
```

This last section of coding (directly above this) compiles and runs, but doesn't check for duplicates.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. What do you mean by *"The last one works, but allows duplicates."*?

Comment: Clear as mud. The quality of your question is directly proportional to the quality of the answer(s) you will receive. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, I mean the last coding section is working (i.e. it will compile and run), but it allows duplicates in the end output (not shown).

Comment: (I hope) I have made the question clearer by editing it. Sorry.

Comment: Are you trying to populate the 2d array with all unique values, where each value is from the user??

Comment: Yes. That is what I'm trying to do. And when the user has finished entering the values. I would like each line or the array to be checked for duplicates.

Comment: Ok. What you can do is use the Hashset of integers to keep track of the ints that have been entered by the user. Whenever you get a input from the user first check if it is in the hashset. If it is, then keep prompting them until they enter one that is not in the hashset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are alternative ways to checking for duplicates (e.g. you could loop back through the data you've entered previously into the 2D array in order to check for duplicate values) however here's how I'd go about using a Set to check for duplicates in order to, *Are you trying to populate the 2d array with all unique values, where each value is from the user??* (also - knowing this explicitly in the original post would be very helpful, thanks to Michael Markidis for specifying that)

With a little UX knowledge here, separating the ERROR is def helpful to the end-user, as ERROR + re-input at the same time is confusing.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] num = new int[3][5];
        System.out.println("Before:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num[i]));
        Set<Integer> data = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // 3 rows with 5 numbers each
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                boolean isGoodInput = false;
                while (!isGoodInput) {
                    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter value for line: " + i + " and position: " + j);
                    Integer n = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    if (data.contains(n)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: Try again");
                    } else {
                        num[i][j] = n;
                        isGoodInput = data.add(n);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num[i]));
    }
}
```

Note: the 2D array is limited to your specification in the original post as a 3x5, so you'd have to change these values in multiple places to make different sized arrays - perhaps making these more dynamic could speed up further development of this application in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to accomplish this where you use the hashset to track what has already been inserted into the 2D array:

```
int[][] num = new int[3][5];
Set<Integer> check = new HashSet<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{ // 3 rows, 5 numbers
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        int n = 0;
        do
        {
            n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter value for row " + i + " and position " + j));

        } while (!check.add(n)); // keep looping if it was in the hashset

        // add it to the array since we know n is not a duplicate at this point
        num[i][j] = n;
    }
}
```